# How to style the data being pulled from a db

Tags: css, vb.net

Below is my front end

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblContent"></asp:Label>
```

Backend

```
Dim db As New Db
        lblContent.Text = db.SiteContents.Where(Function(c) c.CTitle = "links").SingleOrDefault.CText
```

Iv tried everything but I cant add styling and all I want to do is change the font size , any ideas?

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried.

Comment: shall do so in the morning :)

Comment: @YashMashwari the list of what i have tried is long , iv tried adding it via front end , inline on the aps label using cssclass , font-size:  , iv tried wrapping it in a div first , iv tried adding the css to the master page , iv tried targeting the generated table. the span. and it registers when i inspect the browser but the font doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

Based on CSS language rules you can add your style by `key = value` like this:

```
lblContent.Style.Add("font-size", "30px")
```

Note that: All you have to set needs to be done before rendering (on load event or somewhere). If you are doing that by a button the page needs to be refreshed.

Comment: thank you i shall try it tomorrow morning :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the frontend, fetch the element using ID and then update the style of the fetched node.

```
document.getElementById("lblContent").style.fontSize = "large";
```

Comment: I shall try it and update you tomorrow :)